# How do you use "timbre of the times" and what does it mean?

Tags: meaning

How do you use "timbre of the times" and what does it mean? I read: **Given the timbre of the times, I wouldn't have done it.** Thanks.

Comment: It's a bit pretentious - but if you want to be even *more* pretentious, use [***zeitgeist***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Zeitgeist) *- the spirit of the time; the taste and outlook characteristic of a period or generation*. If you don't want to be *at all* pretentious, use [***spirit of the age***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22spirit+of+the+age%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)

Comment: If one musician uses this phrase speaking to another, maybe it would not be pretentious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Timbre of the times* is used idiomatically. Literally, **[timbre](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/timbre)** means

> the characteristic quality of sound that distinguishes one voice or musical instrument from another or one vowel sound from another: it is determined by the harmonics of the sound and is distinguished from the intensity and pitch

Effectively, it means *tone*.  This is often extended to refer to the tone of a thing or a broader abstract like *times*, meaning a given period of time.

The phrase often suggests the general sociopolitical atmosphere of a given era.

As pointed out by FumbleFingers, it is a bit pompous and would, at best, be considered poetic, at worst, clichéd.